# sed - find multiple phrases and replace them

Tags: sed

Got sed command which search one phrase and if found then whole line is replaced.

`sed 's/.*phrase.*/123/'`

That works great but how to use multiple phrases and if even one of them is found then replace whole line?

Was trying command below but no success:

`sed 's/.*phrase1|phrase2.*/123/'`

Using GNU sed.

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your tried code, Add samples of input and expected output too in your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an alternation operator like this:

```sh
sed 's/.*\(phrase1\|phrase2\).*/123/' # POSIX BRE way
sed -E 's/.*(phrase1|phrase2).*/123/' # POSIX ERE way
```

In POSIX BRE, `\(phrase1\|phrase2\)` means a capturing group that matches either `phrase1` or `phrase2`. `\|` is a *GNU extension* for an alternation operator in a POSIX BRE pattern.

In POSIX ERE (enabled with `-E` option), you need to remove the backslashes from the above mentioned constructs: `(phrase1|phrase2)`.

Grouping is necessary as it makes the alternation apply only to the contructs grouped, i.e. `.*phrase1\|phrase2.*` would match either anything from the start till the last `phrase1` string or `phrase2` till the end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you need to put the different phrases between parentheses. Also, if you want to replace all occurrences of your pattern you need to add g at the end.

You can take a look at the docs:
https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html